# Is there any analogue of $\pi$ for non-Archimedean Euclidean fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, transcendental-number-theory

Let us recall that a *Euclidean field* is an ordered field in which every positive element has a square root. Given a Euclidean field $F$, we can consider the ``Euclidean'' plane $F^2$ endowed with the standard Euclidean $F$-valued "metric". We can mimic the standard way of defining the length of the unit circle $\{(x,y)\in F^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$, considering the set $A$ of lengths of incribed polygons and the set $B$ of superscribed polygons around the circle. It can be shown that each element of the set $A$ is strictly smaller than each element of $B$, so $2\pi$ can be defined as the Dedekind cut determined by the sets ${\downarrow}A=\{x\in F:\exists a\in A\;(x\le a)\}$ and ${\uparrow}B=\{x\in F:\exists b\in B\;(x\ge b)\}$, and this approach indeed works if the complement $\Pi=F\setminus({\downarrow}A\cup{\uparrow}B)$ contains at most one point. But for a non-Archimedean field $F$ it can happen that the set $\Pi$ is infinite, so there is no natural way to determine which element of the set $\Pi$ (or its completion) should be a countepart of $2\pi$.

> **Question.** Is there any natural way to determine uniquely the length of the unit circle in the "Euclidean'' plane over a non-Archimedean ordered field $F$?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment as asking for non-archimedean fields in the local field sense. It might be an interesting question too but different from the one you ask.

Comment: @Wojowu I hope that the length of the circle defined via the 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure will be equal to supremum of lengths of inscribed polygons. This is the smallest possible value for $2\pi$. As I understand the role of $\pi$ is to identify the algebra of angles with the algebra of lengths in $F^2$ and have a counterpart of the covering map $t\mapsto e^{it}$ (at least at the level of completions).

Comment: What about choosing an embedding of $\mathbb R$ as an ordered field into $F$ (assuming it exists, which I believe in general it won't) and then defining $2\pi$ using that?

Comment: Also, won't your $\Pi$ sometimes have no elements, depending on $F$?

Comment: For non-Archimedean $F$, I think there is an order-preserving isomorphism of $F$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ but moves $\pi$ infinitesimally, and that would give a negative answer to the question.

Comment: @MattF. Of course in this way $\pi$ is defined uniquely up to an infinitesimal, so I asked about some other way of more precise definition of $\pi$. Maybe through the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)/x=1$?

Comment: @Wojowu For local fields, I guess that $2\pi\sqrt{-1}$ has something to do with Tate twists. I do not know whether it has similar cohomological interpretations in OP's context.